# Why textbox is not loading any data?

Tags: vb.net

I want to load some data in my txtlname.textbox, which depends on my textbox1.text, or if I press the button to the txtlname will load depending on what I input in my textbox1.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    disconnect()
    connect()
    Try
        da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select distinct lname FROM tblemployee WHERE emp_id ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read Then

            txtlname.Text = dr("lname").ToString
            txtlname.Refresh()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Plz log in again" & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would change your query to use a parameterized command

```
    da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select distinct lname FROM tblemployee WHERE emp_id =?", con)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text.Trim())
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read Then

        txtlname.Text = dr("lname").ToString
        txtlname.Refresh()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No record found!")
    End If
```

Then, I have added a message in case `dr.Read` return false. (No record matching the where condition)
At least you will know if there is a simple reason why the textbox remains blank.

A final note. If `emp_id` is a numeric field in the table `tblEmployee` the value passed to the `SelectCommand` parameters collection should be converted to an intenger because, as is, it is passed as a string and this could be the source of missing results.