# this is a running program in a dropdown

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dropdownbox

Help this is a running code reading data in a dropdown, but what if I changed it to 
reading data in textbox. What is the simplest code? can anybody suggest or help me? 
please, because my code is always wrong and not reading

```
Private Sub cmbrevlvl_DropDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
        Try
            disconnect()
            connect()
            da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select lname FROM tblemployee WHERE emp_id ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            If dt.Rows.Count Then

                With ComboBox1
                    .DataSource = dt
                    .DisplayMember = "lname"
                    .ValueMember = "lname"
                End With
            Else
                ' ComboBox1.Enabled = True
                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Plz log in again" & ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: was there something wrong with the last answer you got? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21768483/1070452

Comment: yes sir, it still not reading in my textbox, but my code in a dropdown is reading.

Comment: If dt.rows.count that needs to change to if dt.rows.count > 0, meaning there are rows

Comment: Also your not reading anything here your trying to populate a combobox with items,explain more what you want to achieve .

Comment: I did it, sir sorry for my disturb. ^_^